# Is DiscountASP a good host choice for an app that will have mostly foreign traffic?

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net

I've created an ASP.NET MVC application for a client in India.  Most of the web traffic would come from India.  I typically host my apps at DiscountASP, but would this be a good choice for an app whose traffic is primarily from India?

Comment: SO is a programming related Q&A site (which you should have already noticed for your 2 years and 1 month membership period) and unless you would like to ask  a programming related question or you would like to answer a programming related answer please restrain yourself from posting here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how affected your site would be by latency; DiscountASP.NET offers two datacenter locations, the USA (and I believe based on my sites, that it is in California) and Europe (which I believe they say in the UK).

That said, if latency is going to noticeably impact your site/application, then no, it probably wouldn't be a good choice; you'd want a provider that has a datacenter physically closer to the people who are make up the majority of the consumers of your site.

However, just like in programming, don't make the mistake of premature optimization.  If latency doesn't factor into your application right now, then I wouldn't go out of my way to make sure it's hosted on a datacenter near your customers.

Given that you are looking at DiscountASP.NET, that says you are already going to be on shared hosting, which means that resources are going to be in contention, latency might be a non-issue here compared to that.

And even if you do use shared hosting or something with a relatively high latency, you can always migrate your app later (you probably will have other problems with resource contention before latency comes into play).